# I'm looking for help on how to export JSON data from an API call to an CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

Example of the dictionary returned from the api call. UserList contains the dictionary below.

```
{1: {'Email': 'JohnDoe@email.com',
     'FirstName': 'John',
     'Id': {'Value': 1},
     'LastName': 'Doe',
     'Location': '1',
     'UserName': 'JohnDoe'},
 2: {'Email': 'JaneDoe@email.com',
     'FirstName': 'Jane',
     'Id': {'Value': 2},
     'LastName': 'Doe',
     'Location': '2',
     'UserName': 'JaneDoe'},
 3: {'Email': 'FredDoe@email.com',
     'FirstName': 'Fred',
     'Id': {'Value': 1},
     'LastName': 'Doe',
     'Location': '3',
     'UserName': 'FredDoe'}}
```

Code I'm using to try to export the data. I need to export the data with the keys (UserName, FirstName, LastName) as the headers. The dictionary is saved in the UserList variable.

```
with open('Test.csv', 'w') as f:
    fieldnames = ['UserName', 'FirstName', 'LastName']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for data in UserList:
        writer.writerow([UserList[data][f] for f in fieldnames])
```

Below is the error I'm getting...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 6, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/csv.py", line 155, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/csv.py", line 148, in _dict_to_list
    wrong_fields = rowdict.keys() - self.fieldnames
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you need to iterate through individual elements.

What you're getting right now is, in your first iteration:

> data, UserList[data]
>
> 1, {'Email': 'JohnDoe@email.com', 'FirstName': 'John', 'Id': {'Value': 1},'LastName': 'Doe','Location': '1',   'UserName': 'JohnDoe'}

Hence... what you need to do is:

```
with open('Test.csv', 'w') as f:
    fieldnames = ['UserName', 'FirstName', 'LastName']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for data in UserList:
        # since you only want to write a subset of the dictionary, you'll need to remove the unwanted keys
        del UserList[data]['Id']
        del UserList[data]['Email']
        del UserList[data]['Location']

        writer.writerow([UserList[data][f] for f in fieldnames])
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: Thanks hd1 but it looks like I'm now getting a different error.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 6, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/csv.py", line 155, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/csv.py", line 148, in _dict_to_list
    wrong_fields = rowdict.keys() - self.fieldnames
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: Maybe you could edit your question with the output of my code? Thanks

Comment: Updated. Thanks again for looking at this.

Comment: Many thanks...you're insight is really helpful. For some reason writer.writerow([UserList[data][f] for f in fieldnames]) still gave me an error but I was able to get the output I need with writer.writerow([UserList[data]).

Comment: I suspect (and I'm sure somebody will correct me if I'm wrong) that a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) returns a generator and not the list itself.